# Gravitation and the QFT vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, quantum-gravity, vacuum, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I'm asking this to get yet another lesson in the inability of QFT and GR to cohabit. Many people believe GR must yield to quantization. The question here is as to why the activity of the vacuum cannot be imagined as having some sort of baseline and the gravitational force having some origin in this baseline. And, of course then, that there could exist variations from this baseline on a more fundamental level than the wavelike disturbances of QFT. The variations I intend may have to do with types of virtual particle-antiparticle pair eruptions favored at a particular location, tendency toward shorter or longer lifespans of such events, etc.

Is it just that it is impossible to say anything meaningful about gradings in the living vacuum, and that such hypothetical gradings, however dynamically conjured, could not ever come to mimic aspects of a GR like picture?...due to subtle stuff like violation of basic physical principles and such.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question. What do you mean by "activity," "strength of activity," and "baseline?" In the second sentence you seem to be describing the Einstein field equations...? Why is the second sentence phrased in the negative? The Einstein field equations would simply be the classical limit of a theory of quantum gravity, just as Maxwell's equations are the classical limit of QED.

Comment: @Ben: I believe OP means that from the point of view of GR, vacuum is a calm place whereas in QFT there are fluctuations generating virtual pairs. One has to reconcile this somehow via fluctuating background (and it's not obvious how). As for quantization: by this one means "classical theory -> quantum theory" through replacement of functions on phase space by observables. Not all quantum systems are obtained this way and it's very probable that QG is one of them, i.e. you need truly quantum-theoretical approach. It will of course also contain a classical limit but that's something else...

Comment: My impression from following efforts of quantizing gravity over the years is that the difficulty comes from the spin 2 graviton that needs to be exchanged which cannot fit in a re normalizable perturbative expansion a la QED etc.

Comment: @anna: I don't believe spin 2 is a problem. It's possible to include spin 2 particles in other ways (including supersymmetry, modifying Lagrangian, etc.). Rather, the problem lies in the precise form of the GR Lagrangian. Nor is the non-renormalizability itself a problem: by now we understand that effective theories (such as Fermi's theory of weak interactions) need not be renormalizable to be perfectly usable upto some scale. It just means they break up at higher scales...

Comment: @Marek you are referring to supergravity? It dates me, but I have the impression that they do not have computable diagrams, and that only in string theories the situation between QFT and gravity is resolved, but any enlightenment is welcome.

Comment: @Ben: By "activity" I mean the virtual particle-antiparticle pair production. And by "strength of activity" I mean what kind of virtual particles are produced, how long they last, etc. I'm interested in whether this "strength" could somehow "be" gravity.

Comment: @anna: supergravity is a low-energy limit of string theory and of course the diagrams there are perfectly computable. In fact, that's what AdS/CFT correspondence is all about: transfer hard problems from field theory to supergravity and back. Naturally, supergravity itself isn't a "theory of everything", if that's what you asking; for that you need strings...

Comment: @Georg: I have edited it heavily, though mostly on a semantic level I'm afraid. Might be a crackpot, but I think the question is fun (and funny), and is still hoping to learn something more about the topic than the little I presently know.

Comment: @Anders I : Are You shure that Your answer has some relation to my comment?

Comment: @ Georg: Sorry, I meant it in a most embarrassed sort of way; The question is obviously an easy target since I cannot imagine it doesn't reveals a lack of understanding of very basic physical principles.  These are of course the things I hope to learn about. Perhaps I'm just a guy too much in love with the vacuum.

Comment: And kind regards to everybody here by the way

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ask questions that were more specific, the kind of thing where you're almost able to figure out the answer yourself, but not quite.